# SSIS Drop database error

Tags: ssis, transactions

I want to drop database from SSIS and I've used **Execute SQL Task** to execute next statement:

```
USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE test;
GO
```

But, when I execute package with this task, I've got an error:

`[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DROP DATABASE test" failed with the following error: "DROP DATABASE statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

I've put this task into Sequence Container and on container I set option Transaction to **Required**, because I have more tasks in container. Error is showed on first task, which I explained.

Is it possible to delete the database on my way, our there is some other solution for my problem?

Comment: Have used tried just doing the `DROP Database Test;` The GO Commands are SSMS specific I believe, and they don't work with `Execute SQL Task`

Comment: That does not sound right. Your drop database cannot be supported by a transaction. So hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the properties of this `Execute SQL Task` to change the Transaction option from the default of `Supported` to `Not Supported`

This may defeat your purpose in setting the Sequence Container to Required as you can't roll back a database drop.

Comment: It really helps, thank you much. Can you eventually show me reference where I can get list what is allowed in transaction in SSIS